# How to change Lyx's default font for LaTeX code?

Tags: lyx

Lately i've been working with tikz code to create diagrams. As you may know, this requires several lines of code so it is becoming hard to analyze my documents inside Lyx. is there any way to change LaTeX code font? or to change it size?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can do this by using the local layout. Take a look at Help > Customization. There are font type and size tags in the layout format. Also note that you can zoom out.

Comment: thanks, hadn't noticed that fixed width typography was exactly the one i was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lyx >Preferences >typography >fixed width

Comment: Can this be updated for LyX 2.1.4? Typography is no longer under preferences.